# Sqlplus: Command not found

Tags: bash, shell, oracle-database

I have two virtual machines ubuntu, one is a server when I installed oracle 11g express, and the other is a simple client.
My goal is to run an sql query remotely from the client machine.
So I prepared the query and I sent it to the server. But in the following of the script and after the establishment of the connection to the server, sqlplus dosen't work. And it shows me the following error:

Sqlplus: Command not found

in this work i use this scrpit:

```
#! /bin/bash

read -p "saisir votre requete: "  req

printf "%s\n" "$req" > t1.txt

sed -e 's/[;,()'\'']/ /g;s/  */ /g' t1.txt > t.txt

`tr -s '[[:blank:]]' '\n' < t.txt `|

  while IFS= read -r word; do

if ! [[ "$word" =~ $(echo ^\($(paste -sd'|' ./req.txt)\)$) ]]; then

var=$(base64 <<< $word)


sed -i -e "s/$word/$var/g" t1.txt
fi

  done

enter code here

scp requete.sql cloud1@1.0.0.1:/home/cloud1

#Conection to the Server

ssh cloud1@1.0.0.1 '/home/cloud1/Cloud-Serv'
```

and the file Cloud-Serv contains the following code:

```
#! /bin/bash
"echo "Connection is done !"

sudo service oracle-xe start

sqlplus / as sysdba

exit
```

Comment: It's not so much that `sqlplus` doesn't work, it's that the command hasn't been found. Have you actually installed it?

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: sqlplus is in the script serveur, so i tried to execute this script. So the command is actually installed

Comment: Is sql plus in the $PATH variable or you could mention the entire path while invoking sqlplus. Btw you might have a typo there with the Sqlplus ( the S should be in lower case ).

Comment: Does the client,have an oracle client installed?

Comment: no the client don't have oracle installed

Comment: @AomineDaiki if you haven't installed the Oracle client software on the client, you'll not have `sqlplus`. It's part of the client software package.

Comment: @roaima so should i install oracle client, but in this case how can i execute a remote query. the remote execution is the goal of this work

Comment: @AomineDaiki, oh I see, sorry. You're doing `ssh remote_host sqlplus...` so you don't need sqlplus installed on the client. Then as suggested by Lambert in their Answer you need to address the ORACLE_HOME and PATH environment variables for the non-interactive `ssh` session you're using.

Comment: @roaima:  `ssh serveur@1.0.0.1 sqlplus / as sysdba` is correct?

Comment: @AomineDaiki, no. You need to configure the environment as described in Lambert's answer to you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In most cases, an Oracle instance is running under a special account, say oracle for instance. If you login as that user you need to set the correct environment where `$ORACLE_BASE`, `$ORACLE_HOME` and `$ORACLE_SID` are the most important. Also, the `PATH` variable can be extended to have `$ORACLE_HOME/bin` where `sqlplus` normally resides. Have a look at `oraenv`  to set the correct environment and try to execute `sqlplus` using `$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus`

Comment: when i try oraenv it shows me:   ORACLE_BASE environment variable is not being set since this
information is not available for the current user ID cloud1.
You can set ORACLE_BASE manually if it is required.     How can i edit this parameter

Comment: You can set the parameter ORACLE_BASE using `export ORACLE_BASE=/path/to/oracle`. The ORACLE_HOME can be set using `export ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_BASE/product/11.2.0/Db_1` for instance but I suggest you search for a file called `oratab` where the installed Oracle Home should be listed. Finally you need to set the variable ORACLE_SID using `export ORACLE_SID=<DB_SID>`. If you need this environment often for user cloud1, then consider to place these lines into the `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` for that user.

Comment: i have changed the oracle environnement but it's also dosen't work

Comment: Please update your question with the steps you performed, based on the comments given (the ORACLE environment you have set) and the error message you are now receiving. It might be necessary to start `sqlplus` with `$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus` after you set the environment variables.

Comment: in the end of th file  `~/.bashrc` i have: `export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe` `export ORACLE_SID=XE` `export NLS_LANG=`$ORACLE_HOME/bin/nls_lang.sh` `export ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle` `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`   `export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH`  what change needs to be done

Comment: what does `find /u01 -name sqlplus` result?

Comment: this is the result `/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/sqlplus`  `/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/sqlplus`

Comment: cloud1@localhost's password: 
[cloud1@localhost ~]$ sqlplus / as sysdba
-bash: sqlplus: command not found

[cloud1@localhost ~]$ export ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
[cloud1@localhost ~]$ export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe
[cloud1@localhost ~]$ export ORACLE_SID=XE
[cloud1@localhost ~]$ export PATH=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin:$PATH
[cloud1@localhost ~]$ sqlplus SYS/password as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Tue Apr 14 15:34:09 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to: <truncated else comment to long>

Comment: Just tried to install a fresh install myself and this is what I get. Unfortunately the comment is not formatted very well.... Please provide your exact output when you have set the environment variables.

Comment: the solution is not clear please i need more explication, when i need install this, in the client or the server machine

Comment: On the host (server), where the Oracle XE database is running.

Comment: i do all of this but i don't have any result sqlplus work porperly in the server machine but when i try to run it from the client machine remotly i have command not found

Comment: You need to set (export) the variables in your /home/cloud1/Cloud-Serv file before the sqlplus line. It looks like that your Cloud-Serv line 2 is not right aswell: `"echo "Connection is done !"` should be: `echo 'Connection is done!'`

Comment: ihave this error `ORA-12705: Cannot access NLS data files or invalid environment specified`

Comment: So it looks like `sqlplus` can be found now? Please edit the question and specify which modifications you have made so far and what the exact result is.

Answer (score 0):

In most time, we copy database setup from one server to another server. So, Another server oracle HOME details may mistakenly copied to the new server.

Way to locate the sqlplus in new server.

```
[severdetais scripts]$ locate sqlplus
/oracli/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.3/client_1/sqlplus
/oracli/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.3/client_1/bin/sqlplus
/oracli/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.3/client_1/instantclient/libsqlplusic.so
```

And use the above location in your export properties files like below.

```
export ORACLE_CLIENT=/oracli/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.3/client_1/bin/
export ORACLE_HOME=/oracli/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.3/client_1
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME:$JRE_HOME:$ORACLE_CLIENT:$ORACLE_HOME
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${ORACLE_CLIENT}:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:${ORACLE_HOME}:$ORACLE_HOME/lib
export SQLPATH=${ORACLE_CLIENT}:${SQLPATH}:${ORACLE_HOME}
```

Hope this may resolve the issue!!